# Survival analysis w/ repeated observations of experimental and control units within periods of differing size & trends over the periods

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, survival, experiment-design

I have an experiment called Fear Conditioning Acquisition Protocol. We expose mice to subsequent white sounds followed by short electric shocks through the floor.  Our aim is to let them learn to associate the sound to the shock.  We assess the degree of learning by measuring the freezing of the mouse during the sound exposition.

To do the comparison between the subsequent phases of the experiments we use the average of the freezing of each mouse in every phase.  This is the result graph:
[image: Exposed group]

Then we have another set of mice in which no shock follows the sound (control group)
here's the results:

[image: Control group]

Values are percentage of freezing on phase duration.

My questions are:

1. which test should I use to compare the average freezing between each phase to assess if it's significantly different? I used ANOVA with "Bonferroni's Multiple Comparison Test".
2. graphically the level of freezing is clearly increasing, is it important then to question about the significance of the difference among the freezing levels?
3. how to formally compare the freezing in the exposed and the control group to show that is significantly different?
4. Generate a value that represent the freezing of a mouse to correlate it with the expression of certain proteins. What to use? total freezing over total sound exposition? average freezing?

Comment: What is "freezing"? Specifically, is it a count or a duration?

Comment: it's the time span in which the mouse freeze because scared, it's an indicator of fear. We use percentage of freezing on sound exposition time.

Comment: So it's a duration: total time frozen (even if it occurred in several bouts) divided by total time frozen + moving, is that right?

Comment: Durations are usually modeled with survival analyses like the [Cox model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_models) b/c they are usually censored (ie they have observations that didn't stop freezing b/c the sound stopped / the study ended before they stopped freezing). Do you have any such censored observations? Another possibility, since you divided by total time is, if you don't have any 0%'s or 100%'s is to use Beta regression for continuous proportions. Both of these are fairly advanced.

Comment: In fact I wasn't able to follow you :) The freezing stops necessarily with the end of the sound (Conditioned Stimulus, CS) because a electric shock (Unconditioned Stimulus) is given! We use percentage instead of absolute seconds to compare phases of different lengths. I need a quantitative value to compare freezing in  shocked exposed cases vs controls. UPGRADE: we then would like to compare the freezing level of each mouse to the expression of a certain protein.

Comment: So then there are cases where the duration of freezing could possibly have continued longer if the shock hadn't been delivered at that moment? If so, you have censoring.

Comment: well, it happens in controls. To put it in numbers: cases receive sound for 28s and then 2s of shock, followed by random relax time (no sound) of 60-100s after every shock. In the controls instead the sound continue for full 30s and then the pauses. That's why we use percentage instead of pure time.